# How to customize breadcrumbs NavXT

Tags: wordpress, breadcrumbs

I'm installed `breadcrumb-navxt` for wordpress and it works. But I dont understand how can I customize a clickable links in a breadcrumb path. E.g. I've breadcrumb path: `Main>>News>>Latest_news` in which `Main` and `News` are clickable. So I want to modify News to `Hot News` and change hyper reference of `News` only for this path. How can I do that?

Answer (score 7):

```
add_action('bcn_after_fill', function($bcn_breadcrumb_trail){
    // modify $bcn_breadcrumb_trail->breadcrumbs array of bcn_breadcrumb objects as needed  
});
```

Comment: To change url use method "set_url". To get protected property "url" you should modify file class.bcn_breadcrumb.php and add "get_url" public method : public function get_url(){return $this->url;}

Comment: To change titles for a multilingual custom website I had to modify "class.bcn_breadcrumb.php" from the plugin folder and set "title" property as public in the class. And then I could change the displayed titles, corresponding to the desired language from the function in the answer.